# React-pixi with hooks render 10000 times the same image

Tags: reactjs, optimization, react-hooks, pixi.js

I've been trying to render about 10k+ instances of the same image (with various simple transformations such as rotation/position) on a  element with `react-pixi` using hooks.

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'
import { ParticleContainer, useApp, useTick, Stage, Sprite } from '@inlet/react-pixi'

const texture = PIXI.Texture.from('./images/bg-arrow.png')

export function PixiTest() {

    // Unused right now but I think I have to use this maybe with 
    // `app.stage.addChild( ??? )` ?
    const app = useApp()

    const sprite = (i: number) => <Sprite
        texture={texture}
        anchor={0.5}
        x={i}
        y={i}
        scale={0.01 * i}
    />

    // Very dumb implementation that starts lagging heavily before 1000
    return (
        <ParticleContainer position={[0, 0]} properties={{ position: true }}>
            {
                Array(100).fill(undefined).map((_, i) => sprite(i))
            }
        </ParticleContainer>
    )
}
```

The above is called inside `<Stage {...}></Stage>` tags.

How can I make this work with constant 50-60 fps and 10k+ instances ?

Comment: It would help to know what you're seeing now in terms of performance.

Comment: @mattbasta With this dummy code if I change `Array(100)` to `Array(1000)` I go from smooth 60 fps to 1-2 fps and browser (firefox) becomes nearly unusable.

Comment: I would suggest to look at memory usage ("Memory" tab in Firefox or Chrome devtools etc). Maybe it creates those objects in loop, and then garbage collection is the bottleneck etc? Also, why do you need "react" in this? Why make your life more complicated? :)

Comment: Does this work when using vanilla JS/PIXIJS?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the problem isn't your code, it's the limits of the browser. If I had to guess, it's because the texture that you're using is too high-resolution. You're scaling the sprite down by a factor of 100 in your code. Instead, use an image that's 100x smaller.

Consider:
- If the image is 32x32px, with 100 sprites, you're rendering 102,400 pixels per frame.
- If the image is 32x32px, with 1000 sprites, you're rendering 1,024,000 pixels per frame.
- If the image is 3x3px, with 1000 sprites, you're rendering 9,000 pixels per frame.

Also, it doesn't sound like you need `useApp` at all. I'd also recommend wrapping `PixiTest` in `React.memo`, since it accepts no input and won't ever need to re-render (in React, that is).

Comment: I changed the image size on photoshop to it's 0.1 scale equivalent and noticed almost no change in performance. Sadly this answer didn't help, even though what you recommend are good things. Although I can get to 1k arrows and about 20-30 fps with a non-dummy setup (using common React optimizations), 10k is still about 1 fps, and I'm fairly sure 55fps is doable; I've seen 100k run on [this](https://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/bunnymark_v3/).

Comment: @Mat Keep in mind the bunny example is not fullscreen (makes a diff) and it container is set with all properties off except position (so no scaling and wotnot) which would increase performance.  I can get 1500 dom elements without a notice in fps drop but going above and I loose performance.... https://codepen.io/PAEz/pen/wvKozQg ...going to rewrite that soon to see what happens when its images not dom elements.  My comp is cpu E3-1245 V2 and gpu 1060  OH and if you put a working example up on an online editor we could take a closer look